# Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ be the ideal of $R$ as follows.

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Edit: The matrices is $2\times 2$.

Let $R$ be a ring of upper triangular matrix with entries $\mathbb{Z}_6$ and $I$ be an ideal in $R$ with entries $3\mathbb{Z}_6$. Find the quotient ring $R/I$. Is $R$ field?

To start, first I note that $R$ has 125 elements, but $I$ has 8 elements. So, I can't find the $R/I$ since 8 is not divides 125. Any ideas?

Comment: What size are the matrices? I don't see why $R$ should have 125 elements, it should be some power of 6.

Comment: the matrices is $2\times 2$.

Comment: The ring $R$ has $6^3$ elements since every matrix entry can be chosen in 6 ways, not $125$. If $R/I$ is a field it has to at least be commutative, so $(A+I)(B+I)=(B+I)(A+I)$, and that is true if and only if $AB-BA\in I$ for any $A, B\in R$.

Comment: Oh, I see. I forgotten other element. And hence, $R/I$ has 27 elements right?

Comment: Yes, that's true, but listing all the elements is overkill. Instead inspect the commutativity of $R/I$.

Comment: Yes that's so overkill since 27 elements is too much. But, how to write them in one form?

Comment: I mean, how to write the elements of $R/I$?

Comment: You don't have to write them, you can work with elements of $R$ since $(A+I)(B+I)=(B+I)(A+I)$ if and only if $AB-BA\in I$.

Comment: I'm still confusing

Comment: And then, what is $R/I$? I mean, $R/I = \{ ? \}$ ?

Comment: I agree with $(A+I)(B+I) = (B+I)(A+I)$ iff $AB-BA \in I$ for all $A,B \in R$. But, I still confusing how to write $R/I$?

Comment: But why do you want to write it? It's $R/I=\{A+I \mid A\in R\}$. There's no unique way of writing it since $A+I$ is an equivalence class and has many representatives.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thanks Sir.

Comment: Does $R/I$ field?

Comment: $R/I$ is field since every elements in $R/I$ is a unit and $R/I$ commutative right?

Comment: But, $(R/I\backslash \{0\}, \cdot)$ isn't commutative group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R/I$ is a field then it is at least commutative, hence
$$(A+I)(B+I)=(B+I)(A+I)\iff AB+I=BA+I\\\iff AB-BA=I\iff AB-BA\in I,$$
for any $A,B\in R$. So let
$$A=\pmatrix{a_1 & a_2 \\ 0 & a_3}, B=\pmatrix{b_1 & b_2 \\ 0 & b_3}.$$
After multiplying and subtracting we get
$$AB-BA=\pmatrix{0 & a_1 b_2+a_2b_3 - b_1a_2-b_2a_3 \\ 0& 0}.$$
We can rewrite the top-right entry as $b_2(a_1-a_3)+a_2(b_3-b_1)$, so $AB-BA$ will be in $I$ if and only if $b_2(a_1-a_3)+a_2(b_3-b_1)\equiv 0,3 \mod 6$.

But we can take $b_2=0$, $a_2=2$, $b_3=2$, $b_1=1$ to get $0+2(2-1)=2$ which gives
$$AB-BA=\pmatrix{0 & 2 \\ 0& 0}$$
which is not in $I$.

So the elements of $R/I$ represented by $\pmatrix{p & 2 \\ 0 & q}$ and $\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2}$ do not commute, therefore $R/I$ is not a field.

Answer (score 1):

> Let $R$ be a ring of upper triangular matrix with entries $\mathbb{Z}_6$ and $I$ be an ideal in $R$ with entries $3\mathbb{Z}_6$. Find the quotient ring $R/I$. Is $R$ field?

Hm, I guess you meant "is $R/I$ a field?" Either way, there is a simple way to see why it is not.

In both $R$ and $R/I$ you have an element that looks like $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$. Really in the case of $R$ it should be the element of $\mathbb Z_6$, and in the case of $R/I$ it would be an element of $\mathbb Z_6/3\mathbb Z_6$, but either way $A$ isn't zero.

Now notice $A^2=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.  But of course a field can't have nonzero elements that square to zero. Why? Multiplying $A^2=0$ on the left with the inverse of $A$ would create a contradiction.

Comment: Why you considering $A^2$?

Comment: @user795084 Because I know it will be zero, and that can't happen in a field if $A$ is a nonzero element in a field.

Comment: Sorry? I still not understand yet

Comment: @user795084 Read the last paragraph again, perhaps sit down with a pen and paper, and you will get it. There is nothing I can say that would not repeat things needlessly.

Comment: Oh, I see. Great Sir.